Can you create fusion through scattering?
Could you scatter deuteron molecules (D-D) at high energies into some heavy metal target such that at the time of impact the bond in the deuteron molecule is compressed to such a degree that fusion is possible?

As long as you have high energies, you can force DD to fuse. You dont need anything else.

Generally it would be much easier to sent D ions with an appropriate center-of-mass energy into a deuterated target. Hoping that a scattering event is collinear with the D-D bond is not a good plan, and the molecule is not likely to last very long anyway traversing a solid.

Nice question, I think how can treat this question by uncertainty principle?

Once again a perfectly reasonable question about fusion is closed because the mods don't seem to be familiar with it. The answer is "NO". The issue is that in order to give the D enough energy to overcome the Coulomb barrier it is going to be ionized. As the now-charged particle passes by the other atoms in the solid it will slow down though electrostatic drag and/or collisions. This happens VERY rapidly, long before the statistical chance of it impacting another D. Even if you neutralize it, the first major scattering will ionize it. Google "Colliding beam fusion", the wiki article covers it.

@Sancol. The uncertainty principle is of no help here. D-D fusion rates based on tunneling are unmeasurably low at temperatures which allow for chemical bonds.
